# SQL- Ошибка при присоединении базы данных

Tags: sql, sql-server

При попытке присоединения базы данных на школьном пк, появляется ошибка. Возможно ли это исправить? Можно ли изменить версию базы данных на 612? Так как обноление версии на школьном пк невозможно.

[image: Ошибка]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Версия 706 - это файл базы данных с Sql Server 2012

Версия 663 - это файл базы данных из Sql Server 2008R2 (> SP1)

**С учетом совместимости версий, нет способов работать с версией файла 2012 года на инстансе с версией 2008R2.**

Варианты решения проблемы:

- Апдейт инстанса
- Экспорт схемы и данных стандартными инструментами    экспорта

Comment: Спасибо, только вот я вроде скидываю из 2012 в 2012, раньше кстати работало и присоединялось. А сейчас не знаю почему так. Придется экспортом тогда.

Answer (score 0):

Сделать даунгрейд базы невозможно.
Вам необходимо присоединить базу к актуальной версии SQL Server.
Судя по сообщению ошибки, Вам подойдет SQL Server 2012 и выше.

Можно воспользоваться бесплатной версией Express.